# Is there anything wrong with my code?

Tags: php

I am trying to display the leave history of a particular employee.  But, when I choose a particular month (for example, I choose to display January instead of displaying the history of January), it displays all the history from this year.  Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
<?php
echo 'View the application history by :<select name="date">
        <option value="january" selected="selected">January</option>
        <option value="february" >February</option>
        <option value="march">March</option>
        <option value="april">April</option>
        <option value="may">May</option>
        <option value="june">June</option>
        <option value="july">July</option>
        <option value="august">August</option>
        <option value="september">September</option>
        <option value="october">October</option>
        <option value="november">November</option>
        <option value="december">December</option>';
echo'</select>';
        $value = 'value';
        if($value=='january')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-01-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-01-31'"); 
        }
        else if($value=='february')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-02-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-02-28'");
        }
            else if($value=='march')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-03-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-03-31'");
        }
            else if($value=='april')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-04-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-04-30'");
        }
            else if($value=='may')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-05-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-05-31'");
        }
            else if($value=='june')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-06-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-06-30'");
        }
            else if($value=='july')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-07-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-07-31'");
        }
            else if($value=='august')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-08-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-08-31'");
        }
            else if($value=='september')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-09-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-09-30'");
        }
            else if($value=='october')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-10-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-10-31'");
        }
            else if($value=='november')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-11-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-11-30'");
        }
            else if($value=='december')
        {
             $check_user=mysql_query("select*from employee e, `leave` l where e.emp_id = l.emp_id and l.Emp_ID='".$aid."' and Date_Apply >='2013-12-01' and Date_Apply<'2013-12-31'");
        }

    echo "<table border='1'>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Leave No</th>";
    echo "<th>Leave Start</th>";
    echo "<th>Leave End</th>";
    echo "<th>Date Apply</th>";
    echo "<th>Duration</th>";
    echo "<th>Leave Type</th>";
    echo "<th>Leave Reason</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";


$counter = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_user))
{
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Leave_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Leave_Start'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Leave_End'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Date_Apply'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Duration'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Leave_Type'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Leave_Reason'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>" . $rows['Status'] . "</td>";
    $counter++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: everything

Now you may ask, why?

- Very bad variable naming style
- unreadable code (so manh if-else if -else
- You Repeat yourself all over the code
- No seperation of concern (business logic and presentation is tightly coupled)

Let's start with the 'design' of your code.

What you actually are trying to create is a Form where a user can select a month. A little script that performs a query depending on the month selected and a presentation file that presents the result of the query.

3 things, so split them up into 3 files.

after that, the form will have to comunicate with the script. This should be the GET method since you are getting data (with a filter, the month). The form should perform a GET request to the controller that then fires the little script passing in the selected month (using the php $_GET var) and then pass on the result of that little script to the presentation file (a 'template').

So, now we have sorted out how our application should work. You can go back to work.

However what I think is the real problem: you don't understand how client and server communicate with each other.

PHP = server-side. this way it doesn't know what the user is doing at the Client side.
You therefore have to pass in all the required data (e.g. what month was selected) to the server. Then the server (PHP script in your case) can create the required output that is then shown to the client.